# How to add a class method in addtarget UIButton?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have two classes and one of them I create a button which, I want to call a method in this class.

```
  class blueFooterForImages: UIView{
    //buttons for footer
       let slideButton = UIButton()
       let buttonOnFooter = UIButton()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        //setting buttons
        slideButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.width / 2) - 10 , 10, 30, 30)
        slideButton.addTarget(self, action: "animationFunction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        slideButton.setImage(imageForSlideButton,forState: .Normal)
        self.addSubview(slideButton)}
 }

internal func animationFunction(sender: UIButton!) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.frame.size.width -= 100
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your code, use singleton and send the instance

```
static var sharedInstance : blueFooterForImages?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    blueFooterForImages.sharedInstance = self
   //rest of init code....
}
```

in other class:

```
var button = UIButton(initParams...);
button.addTarget(blueFooterForImages.sharedInstance!,action:"animationFunction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);
```

just make sure that blueFooterForImages.sharedInstance is not nil

(make sure that blueFooterForImages instance was created before you do this)

Comment: hmm it does not work, button It does not react at all.

Comment: i add static var in bluefooter  and then created the object in another class , and it also creates a button with addtarget like you said .

Comment: Everything works , I figured out what the problem was ! Thanks!